# Monte Carlo - Turning Lack of Results into Probability Estimate

Tags: statistics, montecarlo

I had a question about turning the results of a Monte Carlo simulation into a probability estimate where one does not see any occurrences of the event intended to be profiled.

Simulating a scenario with an unknown underlying distribution where I am looking for an outcome which constitutes a 'failure' in the underlying context. I have ran ~ 4,500,000 trials and seen 0 failures. I am assuming that the simulation is programmed 'correctly' given other outcomes which I can measure which are not 'failures'.

Would it be fair to say then that, with 99% confidence, the odds of a failure is approximately 1 in 1,000,000 or less likely under the following reasoning.

If the odds of failure were 1 in a million, then the probability of 0 failures in 4.5M trials would be (1-1/1,000,000)^4,500,000 which is approximate 1%. So therefore the odds of a failure are 1 in 1,000,000 or even less likely with roughly 99% confidence.

Is that sound reasoning?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming problem; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, my advice is to just look at this from a Bayesian point of view -- what's the posterior distribution of the probability of success, given 4.5e6 trials and 0 successes? What fraction of the mass of that distribution is between 0 and 1e-6? Looking at a posterior distribution will make it possible to talk in a coherent way about the problem -- the problem with "confidence" is that everybody wants it to be probability, but it's not.